# Is TFS better than GIT for code management?

Tags: git, github, tfs, version-control

I want to start an individual project just for learning purposes. But, i am not sure if i should use Git or TFS for code management?
Which are Pros and Cons of each of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not the same at all:

- **[git](https://git-scm.com/)** is just a source control (distributed)
- **[TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/tfs-overview-vs.aspx)** is an ALM (Application Lifecycle Management), which manages tickets, sources (including Team Foundation version control (TFVC) or git repos) and builds (jobs for building and deploying)

So the question "Is TFS better than GIT for code management?" cannot really be answered: the scope covered by those tools is vastly different.
Plus, you can use git within TFS anyway if you want.